# Replace output file extension in linux shell command

Tags: linux, shell, csh

Say I have a command, convertImage, which takes some input jpeg, and spits out a new png in the same directory:

```
convertImage --format png photo.jpg -o photo.png
```

I want to make an alias "convertToPng" which takes only one arg, the file:

```
convertToPng photo.jpg
```

My current solution is this:

```
alias convertToPng "convertImage --format png \!:1 -o \!:1.png"
```

However this will name the output file to "photo.jpg.png" and I want it to be named "photo.png". Is there any way to parse the filename first, and then pass that to the convertImage executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input is always jpg then

```
convertToPng photo
alias convertToPng "convertImage --format png \!:1.jpg -o \!:1.png"
```

or give extension as 2nd parameter

```
convertToPng photo jpg
alias convertToPng "convertImage --format png \!:1.\!:2 -o \!:1.png"
```

or last option

```
convertToPng photo.jpg
alias convertToPng "convertImage --format png \!:1 -o `echo $1 | cut -f1 -d'.'`.png"
```

or write a function in your `.bashrc` as follows

```
function convert() 
{
    convertImage --format png $1 -o `echo $1 | cut -f1 -d'.'`.png;
}
```

and execute above `function` as

```
convert photo.jpg
```

I prefer the `function` way as it gives you lot flexibility over `aliases` and you can do much more than just one statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo photo.jpg | awk -F. '{print $1".png"}'
```

This could be used in a command line invocation like so:

```
$ convertImage --format png photo.jpg -o `echo photo.jpg | awk -F. '{print $1".png"}'`
```